# Slow query log is not storing slow queries

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, query-performance

Using 5.6.35 MySQL Community Server (GPL). I have setup the local MySQL instance as follows

```
show variables like '%slow%query%log%'

slow_query_log  ON
slow_query_log_file /usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro-slow.log

general_log ON
```

but I don't see any queries being logged in

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.slow_log;

SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log
```

Both the tables are empty. I am running queries that are running for more than 20 seconds, and my threshold is set fine. Any advice?

Comment: What's the value of the `log_output` variable?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to collect general and slow logs:

- File (this is the default)
- Table (this needs to be specifically enabled)

Based on the info you provided, it looks like MySQL is using the default value for log_output which is "Log output goes to file(s) defined by general_log_file and slow_query_log_file". You can verify this by looking at these files (look in folder /usr/local/mysql/data/ and see what *.log files are there)

If you want the logs to go to database, on a MySQL client when logged in as a privileged user e.g. root:

- `SET GLOBAL log_output='TABLE';`
- `SET GLOBAL general_log=ON;`
- `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=ON;`
- `SET GLOBAL long_query_time=0;`

The above will send global and slow logs to `mysql.general_log` and `mysql.slow_log` tables.

Note that I have set `long_query_time` to 0 seconds i.e. every query goes to `slow_log`(that is lot of output into the table). You can change this to another value that suits your use case.

Also, `general_log` produces a huge amounts of logs so you should only enable it for certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

by default (and in Your case as well)
slow and general log save information into normal OS file

Slow log file in Your case:

```
/usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro-slow.log
```

You can not access data from this file from mysql inside

You can open it manually by editor, or with specialised tools like - [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html)

If You want have this data in table, You need enable writing to table - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-output